# How to save ImageView from API to internal storage?

Tags: android, image, android-studio, imageview, android-bitmap

I'm trying to save the image from API and is always going to catch.

```
public void saveSkin() {
    ivSkinSaver.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bm = ivSkinSaver.getDrawingCache();

    OutputStream Out = null;
    Uri outputFileUri;
    try {
        File mediaFile;
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/Android/data/"
                + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                + "/Files");
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm").format(new Date());
        String mImageName = "MI_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + mImageName);
        Out = new FileOutputStream(mediaFile);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"file saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured. Please try again later.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    try {
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, Out);
        Out.flush();
        Out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: print the stacktrace, `e.printStackTrace()` to know what causes the catch

Comment: @AgiMaulana I printed the stackTrace, and the message is this "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.wellington.lolguide/Files/MI_16032017_1556.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)"

Comment: before `Out = new FileOutputStream(mediaFile);` , create new file `mediaFile.createNewFile()`

Comment: @AgiMaulana Did'nt work, I used the debug and the `Out = new FileOutPutStream(mediaFile);` is null.

Comment: @AgiMaulana and the `e.printStackTrace()` changed the message, now is this: "java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

Comment: you don't need permission to write to internal storage, i guess your internal memory is emulated from sd card. declare permission to write a fle to sd card in manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`